# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not install GRUB... not recognizes Windows 7 in Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

By now I use SSD 240GB with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
When I power on my computer it starts Grub and ask which SO I wanna to open.
My motherboard is a Asus H110 Plus. Grub is installed ad MBR.
To do it I always formar my SSD using a live CD creating a: NTFS + EXT4 + SWAP partition. So I install Windows 7. And after I install Ubuntu that recognizes automatically both systems.

By now I download Ubuntu 20.04 and make same procediment as I said above.
I installed Windows 7 on a NTFS.
So when I was installing Ubuntu showed a messaged: "I should define a EFI partition".

I make it because I created a:
#1: SDA1-FAT32 100MB partition
#2: SDA2-NTFS 100GB partition for windows
#3: SDA3-EXT4 200GB por Linux
#4: SDA4-2GB partition as SWAP. So I could define the SDA1-FAT32-100MB as EFI.

But after installing Ubuntu 20.04 it does not recognizes anymore Windows 7 at SDA2.

I tried to install Grub with: apt-get install grub2 // update-grub2 // grub2-install

But I still have not GRUB.
I still tried to change my BIOS to LEGACY and UEFI...
Bios starts as UEFI my SSD as: Kingston-480GB-Ubuntu
If i take off UEFI and just put my SSD it occurs a error.

What Can I do? Grub is not default system? Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognizes Windows anymore?

Comment: You have to be consistent. UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. If you have newer UEFI hardware use UEFI. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI boot mode  with gpt partitioning since release of Windows 8 in 2012. It released an update to Windows 7 to install in UEFI mode (with Secure boot off). If you really want to now 40 year old BIOS/MBR configuration, then always boot installer in BIOS boot mode. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen 20.10 uses grub for both
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

#1: I disabled UEFI at my bios. Because I have formated my SSD as MSDOS.
(If I had used UEFI I should formated my SSD as GPT. And created a 256mb FAT32 partition to keep EFI).

By the way, I have used LEGACY boot (not UEFI), I did not create the 256mb FAT32 partition and I skip this at the instalation. Ubuntu 20.04 show a message that it was recommended creating a EFI partition, but I assumed this risk.

#2: When installing finished. Grub was installed and recognized Windows 7 but did not show.
So, I edit: **/etc/default/grub**

**GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu and GRUB_TIMEOUT=10**

*(I found that at the post:
https://medium.com/@leijerry888/get-grub-menu-back-after-installing-ubuntu-20-04-alongside-windows-dab5de5afc37)*

After that it could do Dual Boot.
My Ubuntu 20.04 recognized automatizally Windows 7 at sda2.
GRUB is shown at every boot.

Thanks very much.